# (Circular) (PowerPoint like) transitions between two div's

Tags: javascript, html, css, powerpoint

I have been searching for hours now. Animate.css seems to be pretty good but it only contains some basic animations like moves and scales. But i need something more difficult.
I would like to create a transition between two div elements. The first div is in the foreground and the second behind it. I would like to achieve some PowerPoint-Like transitions between them. I've posted an example Transition I would like to achieve.

[image: This is a circular transition example.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to split or transform a div with text inside in the way shown. But I come up with a similar transition that could give some hints or might be even satisfactory.

#### How it works

I use an overlay composed of eight triangles. These triangles can be designed in CSS like this:

```
.triangle-down-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 150px solid darkgreen;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}
```

And then arranged like this:

[image: overlay triangle illustration]

The triangles will appear one after the other to hide the first slide. Then they will disappear in a second turn one after the other to reveal the second slide (*two* turns is what's different from the OP's transition!). You can use this overlay then again when changing to the third slide or use another one, maybe with other colors for the triangles.

#### Result

You can check it out and play around in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3v1Lcr9p/).

```js
$('#next-slide').click(function() {
  var triangles = $('#overlay1 div');
  showTriangles(triangles).done(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#slide1').hide();
      hideTriangles(triangles);
    }, 200);
  });

});

function showTriangles(triangles) {
  var promises = [];
  $(triangles).each(function(i) {
    var def = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(triangles[i]).css('opacity', '1');
      def.resolve();
    }, 200 * i);

    promises.push(def);
  })

  return $.when.apply(undefined, promises).promise();
}

function hideTriangles(triangles) {
  $(triangles).each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(triangles[i]).css('opacity', '0');
    }, 200 * i);
  });
}
```

```css
#next-slide {
  margin-left: 350px;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide,
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#slide1 {
  z-index: 2;
}
#slide2 {
  z-index: 1;
}
#overlay1 {
  z-index: 100;
}
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.triangle1 {
  left: 150px;
}
.triangle2 {
  left: 150px;
}
.triangle3 {
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}
.triangle4 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
.triangle5 {
  top: 150px;
}
.triangle6 {
  top: 150px;
}
.triangle-up-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 150px solid white;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
}
.triangle-up-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 150px solid white;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}
.triangle-down-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 150px solid white;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
}
.triangle-down-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 150px solid white;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide1" class="slide">
  Slide 1.
  <br>Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! I wanna help you. But I can't give you this case, it don't belong to me. Besides, I've already been through too much shit this morning over this case to hand it over
  to your dumb ass.
</div>

<div id="overlay1" class="overlay">
  <div class="triangle triangle1 triangle-up-left"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle2 triangle-down-right"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle3 triangle-up-right"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle4 triangle-down-left"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle5 triangle-down-right"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle6 triangle-up-left"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle7 triangle-down-left"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle8 triangle-up-right"></div>
</div>

<div id="slide2" class="slide">
  Slide 2.
  <br>Some wonderful lorem ipsum text. Did you know dolor sit amet? At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
  elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
</div>

<button id="next-slide">Next slide</button>
```

[image: Resulting animation]

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Thank you. This Transition Looks great, but __do you know a way to do it more smoothly?__ Because of my screen capture program my example doesn't look smooth as well. Sorry, that's my mistake. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: In general for making a transition smoother, you would have to either add more frames or make the whole transition complete faster. The problem with adding more frames is, that it would require more triangles (as 1 frame = 1 triangle in this example) and I don't see a way to achieve this with CSS. So here is a [faster version](https://jsfiddle.net/3v1Lcr9p/1/) and here is a [version with transition](https://jsfiddle.net/3v1Lcr9p/4/) on the opacity of the triangles, which makes it a little smoother without speeding up everything.

Comment: Thanks. That makes the Transition much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Try Magic Animations, https://www.minimamente.com/example/magic_animations/. They offer quite a few different animations and transitions.

Comment: Thanks. But that's not the solution I asked for. I already know Frameworks for movements, scales and rotations. I need real transitions ;-)